# How to allow last resnet block to be trainable?

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, resnet

i want to make the last resnet block to be trainable, as i suspect that the features learned from ImageNet may not be directly relevant to my image classification problem.

i managed to train vgg16 last block, and wonder how the same can be implemented also to resnet.

```
model.get_layer('block5_conv1').trainable = True
model.get_layer('block5_conv2').trainable = True
model.get_layer('block5_conv3').trainable = True
model.get_layer('block5_pool').trainable = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. In general, it's a good idea to keep most layers unchanged, and just retrain the last few layers. For example, this is how you'd freeze all layers but the last one.

```
for layer in model.layers[0:-1]:
  layer.trainable = False
```